# Using find.() to find overlapping sub-strings in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, find

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around why my find() works/doesn't work. I am attempting to count overlapping sub-strings of 'sas' This first block of code works and prints out 3, my desired result.

```
x = 'sasidsasas'
sasnum = 0
iteration = 0

while True:
    iteration = x.find('sas', iteration)
    if iteration >= 0:
        iteration += 1
        sasnum += 1
    else:
        break

print(sasnum)
```

This second block of code does not work (i.e. it prints out 0).

```
 x = 'sasidsasas'
sasnum = 0
iteration = 0

while True:
    iteration = x.find('sas', len(x))
    if iteration >= 0:
        iteration += 1
        sasnum += 1
    else:
        break

print(sasnum)
```

Obviously, my question revolves around the second part of find.(). Now I believe what is happening, in the first block of code, is that the iteration value is being set to the beginning of the 'sas' it finds plus 1, therefore when it loops back around it starts looking for the next 'sas' in the string. In the second block of code I am telling it to begin looking at the end of the string, therefore it immediately breaks out.

Is that correct or am I thinking of this completely wrong?

Comment: If the first one works, why are you using the second one?  What did you expect the second one to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [`find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find):

> Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure.

Addressing the first part of your question:

> Now I believe what is happening, in the first block of code, is that the iteration value is being set to the beginning of the 'sas' it finds plus 1, therefore when it loops back around it starts looking for the next 'sas' in the string.

That's right. Here's what happens:

1. On the first iteration `find` returns 0, which you assign to `iteration` and increment to 1.
2. On the next iteration, `find` considers the substring 'asidsasas' (`x[1:]`), and assigns 5 to `iteration` (the next occurrence of 'sas' in `x`), which gets incremented to 6.
3. On the third iteration, `find` considers the substring 'asas' (`x[6:]`) and finds a third occurrence of the substring at index 7. This gets assigned to `iteration`, which then gets incremented to 8.
4. On the fourth iteration, `find` fails to find any more occurrences, so it returns -1 causing the while loop to exit.

Addressing the second part of your question:

> In the second block of code I am telling it to begin looking at the end of the string, therefore it immediately breaks out.

What's happening in the second block is that you're telling it to *begin* looking at an index past the end of the string. That causes `x.find` to return -1 (failure). Because -1 is not greater or equal to 0, `sasnum` does not get incremented and the loop is immediately exited.

So yeah, you're right on this too.